# Safe way to retrieve secret keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords, password-recovery

I'm working on an app that has a red button. What that means is that every client account has two (secret) keys that are automatically generated. When someone enters those keys on a special (public) page, a certain process will be set in motion. The process is not critical, but

That's all taken care of, the keys are automatically generated on user account creation, stored encryped in the database and are shown to the user once so he can distribute the keys as he sees fit. He can of course reset the keys if he wants to.

The thing is, some clients keep forgetting the keys. Our solution is to reset the keys and redistribute the new keys, but for some clients that's just not practical. I'd like to offer the option of retrieving the keys without resetting them.

My idea was to be able to decrypt the keys using the user's password, meaning that the already logged in user would have to enter his password again, which was used to encrypt the keys and is now used to decrypt them. I'm just not sure how that would technically work (is there an encryption/decryption algorithm that I could use?) and whether there's anything I should consider before employing such a technique.

Does anyone have any ideas on this? Maybe even a better suggestion?

Comment: This is super over-wrought. Simple password authentication and traditional password-reset-via-email will suffice, provided you're using SSL. If you're not using SSL, it doesn't matter how many keys you use or how securely they're generated...

Comment: You could look at the keys as sort of a username/password combination, but that's not the point at all. The point is that we need to be able to retrieve both keys somehow. Key-reset-via-email combined with SSL is what we use now and it does _not_ suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You want to check out ciphers like [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard).

I'd check out [this gisthub example](https://gist.github.com/728456) on how to use Ruby and AES for encryption and decryption.

Comment: I'll check it out. Thank you. It does pose the question of how we'd handle password changes and resets though. I should think this through some more. Any ideas are welcome.